# Display triangle shape using asterisk using the substring method

Tags: java, substring, space, shapes

I would like for my program to be in the shape of a triangle with space in between like the photo below.
Heres my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Triangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String space= "          ";
        space.replaceAll("", " ");
        int i = input.nextInt();
        while (i > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j <1; j++)
                System.out.print("*"+space.substring(0,0)+"*");
            System.out.println();
            i--;
        }
    }
```

when i run this code the output is this

```
**

**


**

**

**

**

**

**

**
```

I would like the output to look like this:

[image]

Comment: do you need first or second output?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your inner for loop doesn't serve any purpose. It runs only once. The logic would be same even if you remove it.

```
for (int j = 0; j <1; j++)
```

Secondly, I feel you wanted to do something like this :

```
System.out.print("*"+space.substring(i)+"*");
```

Make sure your string is big enough than the index i

```
String space= "                                       ";
```

Comment: Remove the for loop. Change the substring as mentioned

Comment: now my output is                                                       not shape as a triangle anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=input.nextInt();
    for (int j=0; j<(i-1); j++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println("*");
    for (int j=1; j<(i-1); j++)
    {
        for (int k=0;k<(i-1-j); k++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print("*");
        for (int k=0;k<(j*2)-1; k++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println("*");
    }
    for (int j=0; j<(i*2-1); j++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using something like `String.format("%3s, "*")` you can define the width (here: 3) and therefore the white-space of the output. If you add some clever code to define the width for each line, you can save yourself a lot of headaches.

In addition it is important to know that only a font with a fixed letter spacing will do the trick (like Currier New).